# Div following pointer on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I want to show a floating div that follows the pointer when you're hovering certain divs, so far I found this piece of code with jquery that works when hovering the whole body, but what I want is to work on certain divs:

CSS

```
<div id="tail">mouse tail</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#tail').css({
       left:  e.pageX + 20,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

I tried `bind` to specific selector but it didn't work.

The div should disapear when you hover outside the div and reappear when you hover in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the div display to none when the mouse leaves and display block when it enters

```js
$('.something').bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#tail').css({
       left:  e.pageX + 20,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});

$('.something').bind('mouseleave', function(e){
    $('#tail').css({
       display:  'none'
    });
});
$('.something').bind('mouseenter', function(e){
    $('#tail').css({
       display:  'block'
    });
});
```

```css
#tail {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.something {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tail">mouse tail</div>

<div class='something'> stuff </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Target the specific divs, give them onmouseenter/onmouseleave events:

```
#tail {
  position: fixed;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
};
```

---

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  $('#tail').css({
   left:  e.pageX + 20,
   top:   e.pageY
  });
});

var myDiv = document.getElementById('tail');
var targets = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myTargets'));

targets.map(function(target){
    target.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
        document.getElementById('tail').classList.remove('hidden')
    });
    target.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
        document.getElementById('tail').classList.add('hidden')
    });
});
```